# Classloading in EJB module packaged in EAR

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, packaging, ear

I'm currently developing a prototype that relies on Java EE 7. Maven is used for dependency management and the plugin maven-ear-plugin for the final EAR build. The latter is then deployed on a wildfly 10.0 application server.

The project structure is as follows (simplified):

- controler-api
- controler-impl
- model-api
- model-impl
- system-parent (maven parent package)
- system-ear (to generate ear)
- view-webapp

The EAR consists of the two ejb3 modules "controler-impl" and "model-impl", as well as the web app "view-webapp". The maven-ear-plugin is configured accordingly:

```
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>  
    <configuration>  
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>  
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>  
        <modules>  
            <ejbModule>  
                <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>  
                <artifactId>model-impl</artifactId>  
            </ejbModule>  
            <ejbModule>  
                <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>  
                <artifactId>controler-impl</artifactId>  
            </ejbModule>  
             <webModule>  
                <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>  
                <artifactId>view-webapp</artifactId>  
                <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>  
            </webModule>  
        </modules>  
    </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

So far, everything has worked out well and the prototype is already in a decent state.

However, I have been facing a problem for days I cannot cope with:

In the controler-impl, I want to use reflections (org.reflections) to determine classes that have been enriched with a specific annotation. Hence, I added the corresponding dependency and the jar reflections-0.9.10.jar is stored in the lib folder of the EAR correctly.

But at run time, I always encounter a ClassNotFoundException showing me that the class loader in the ejb module controler-impl is not able to find the classes in reflections-0.9.10.jar. For debugging, I went through the classloader hierarchy and checked which packages and classes are available for them.

I found three classloaders:

1. ModuleClassLoader (parent refers to 2)
2. AppClassLoader (parent refers to 3)
3. ExtClassLoader (parent is null)

None of them are able to access the classes in reflections-0.9.10.jar deposited in the central EAR lib folder. This is weird as I expected this key folder to be accessible by the all ear modules.

Of course, I looked for existing solutions in the web. For instance, I found the following article explaining the class loader hierarchy/separation in more details.

[Packaging EJB 3 Applications - Developer.com](http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3670496_2/Packaging-EJB-3-Applications.htm)

Based on Table 2 in this article, I assumed that I have to add a manifest file in the ejb module. Of course, I tried this by changing configuration of the maven-ear-plugin or even adding the maven-ejb-plugin to the modules. But I always encountered the error "Class Path [...] in [...] does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference" and the basic problem of the missing reference to the EAR lib folder still exists (see stacktrace below).

I guess that I likely have to configure the maven-ear-plugin and/or maven-ejb-plugin better (whatever that means) - does anybody have an idea how to do that? Or did I miss something important?

Thanks a lot

Nicolas

***Updates due to reqests in comments***

*POM of controler-impl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>prototype</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../system-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>controler-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Controler Implementation (EJB)</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- internal dependencies (provided by EAR) -->
        <!--  [...] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>controler-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>model-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>model-impl</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- external dependencies (provided by EAR) -->
        <!--  [...] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
     </build>
</project>
```

*application.xml of EAR (generated by maven-ear-plugin)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>system-ear</display-name>
  <description>...</description>
  <module>
    <ejb>model-impl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>controler-impl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>view-webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

*Stack trace excerpt showing that reflections-0.9.10.jar is not accessible*

```
09:48:27,222 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component AccessControlManagerImpl for method public abstract org.apache.shiro.web.env.WebEnvironment com.domain.abc.controler.main.api.security.AccessControlManager.getPermssions(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.domain.abc.controler.main.api.security.AccessControlManager$$$view4.getWebEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.domain.abc.controler.main.impl.security.AccessControlManager$2108109816$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.getWebEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.AccessControlManager$2108109816$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getWebEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at com.domain.abc.view.frontend.webapp.security.CustomViewEnvLoaderListener.createEnvironment(CustomViewEnvLoaderListener.java:23)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:344)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reflections/Configuration
    at com.domain.abc.controler.main.impl.security.AccessControlManagerImpl.postConstruct(AccessControlManagerImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.reflections.Configuration from [Module "deployment.prototype.ear.controler-impl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 109 more
```

Comment: Can you post your application.xml and the stacktrace?

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the *pom.xml* file of the module that uses your *reflections-0.9.10.jar*?

Comment: It seems that the issue might result of the **provided** on your *reflections* dependency of the *controler-impl* module. Do you also have the *reflections* dependency declared in your EAR?

Comment: The problem could be that you try to access EJB jars from one-another. I don't think this is possible by default. Configure your standalone.xml: 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
</subsystem> 
according to this guide: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: @aribeiro the reflections dependency is defintely declared in the EAR and the lib is included in the EAR successfully

Comment: @highstakes I don't try to access EJB jars from one another. I try to access classes of the 3rd party library reflections-0.9.10.jar from the EJB module controler-impl

Comment: @nmundbrod, that's what I thought. You need to remove the dependency from your EAR *pom.xml* file and also remove the *provided* keyword from your *reflections* dependency of the *controler-impl* module. Maven knows how to deal with transitive dependencies and it will still appear on the EAR lib.

Comment: @aribeiro alright, I will try this and give feedback as soon as something's changed. thx

Comment: @aribeiro you were right, that solved my problem. thx a lot! In general, it's just very important to check the scope of every dependency in multi-module EAR projects... (i also use web-fragements in the webapp)

Comment: @nmundbrod, then, if it's okay with you, I'll place an answer with my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue results of the **provided** on your *reflections* dependency of the *controler-impl* module.

Having the dependency as provided, you weren't binding it to the class-path of your JAR, even though it was being fetched and placed into your EAR/lib folder.

You need to remove the dependency from your EAR *pom.xml* file and also remove the **provided** keyword from your *reflections* dependency of the *controler-impl* module.

Doing that, you require that Maven binds the dependency to your JAR's class-path and, by transitivity, places it inside your EAR/lib folder.